# Shell - Get string in a file between chars

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I need to get a value from a variable in a file:
This is the content of the file

```
variable1=100    ;    value1 
variable2=200    ;    value2 
variable3=300    ;    value3 
variableN=400    ;    valueN
```

I want to save variable's 3 in another variable via a shell script, between 300 and ';' could be variable number of spaces.

Here's my code:

```
awk -F "=" '/variable3/ {print $2}' /opt/myFile.ini
```

this the output:

```
300                             ;    value3
```

How can I get only "300" ?
Better using cut, or tr ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[=;[:space:]]+' '$1=="variable3"{print $2}' file
300
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'=| ' '/variable3/ && $2==300{print $2}' Input_file
```

To save it into a shell variable use:

```
var=$(awk -F'=| ' '/variable3/ && $2==300{print $2}' Input_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but this print nothing

Comment: @DDBE, When you run `awk -F'=| ' '/variable3/ && $2==300{print $2}' Input_file` then it will print value? For command `var=$(awk -F'=| ' '/variable3/ && $2==300{print $2}' Input_file)` you need to print value of `var` by doing `echo "$var"`, could you please do lemme know which thing didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
awk -F "=" '/variable3/ {print $2}' /opt/myFile.ini | cut -d ";" -f 1 | tr -d "\n\r\t"
```

Comment: IMHO, you need not to use these many commands, to simply get `300` value my code should work, it worked for me when I tested it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61360071/5866580

Answer (score 0):

using `sed`

```
sed -nE /variable3/'s#.*(=.*;).*#\1#g'p  < /opt/myFile.ini |   tr -d ' =;'
```

Demo

```
$cat file1.txt
variable1=100    ;    value1
variable2=200    ;    value2
variable3=300    ;    value3
variableN=400    ;    valueN
$sed -nE /variable3/'s#.*(=.*;).*#\1#g'p  <file1.txt |   tr -d ' =;'
300
$
```